# Acentuação no C++ VisualStudioCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Estou tentando utilizar a acentuação no c++ porém na saída o texto continua sem a formatação estou utilizando o visual studio code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>

int main ()
{   
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
    int NumVidas = 5;
    int Pontuacao = 1350;

    std::cout << "Inicio de jogo\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Numero de vidas: "<< NumVidas << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Pontuação: " << Pontuacao << "\n";

    NumVidas -= 1;
    Pontuacao -= 350; 

    std::cout << "\nNumero de vidas: "<< NumVidas << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Pontuação: " << Pontuacao << "\n";
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Use "pt-br" como locale. Teste o retorno de `setlocale()` para ver se o locale foi aceito. Rode `locale -a` em sua máquina para ver a lista de locales se está usando Linux ou mesmo Windows se tem por exemplo git instalado.

Answer (score 1):

Para quem passar por o mesmo problema no futuro, resolvi da seguinte forma no VSCODE:

Cliquei no canto inferior direito onde tem `UTF-8` e cliquei em `Reopen with Encondig` e selecionei `Western(ISO 8859-1) iso88591`.
Lembrando que precisa ter compilado o código pelo menos uma vez. Logo após ele irá "formatar o seu código" e então você precisa reescrever as palavras com os acentos novamente.

Para por o `ISO 8859-1` por padrão você precisa entrar em **File > Preferences > Settings** e em `seaching` digitar **encoding** e em **Files: Enconding** selecionar o `Western (ISO 8859-1)`.

Lembrando que estou utilizando o Visual Studio Code e, creio que, em outras IDEs tipo o Visual Studio não precise desse processo.

Answer (score -1):

1. Pressione `Windows` + `R` e execute o prompt de comando.
2. Digite o comando: cmd.exe /k chcp 65001.
3. Rode seu programa.